How to create and manipulate MP4 video frames using only native Lua?
Question:
I'm working on a project where I need to create an MP4 video and control its frames entirely using Lua, without relying on any external APIs. The goal is to both generate and read video frames.
Details:

I'm looking for guidance on how to:

Create video frames in Lua.
Assemble these frames into an MP4 file.
Read frames from an existing MP4 file.
Since I'm doing this from the ground up, I'm interested in understanding the necessary steps and any Lua functions or techniques that could help me achieve this.

What I Tried:

I've written some Lua code to create an MP4 file with frames, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's my code:
local function create_ftyp_box()
  local major_brand = "isom"
  local minor_version = "\0\0\2\0" -- Version 2.0
  local compatible_brands = "isom" .. "iso2" .. "avc1" .. "mp41"
  local ftyp_data = major_brand .. minor_version .. compatible_brands
  return ftyp_data
end

local function create_mvhd_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"  -- flags
  local creation_time = "\0\0\0\0"
  local modification_time = "\0\0\0\0"
  local timescale = "\0\0\03\xe8"  -- 1000 units per second
  local duration = "\0\0\03\xe8"  -- 1 second duration
  local rate = "\0\0\01\00"  -- 1.0
  local volume = "\0\01\00\00"  -- full volume
  local reserved = "\0\0" .. string.rep("\0", 10)
  local matrix = string.rep("\0", 36)  -- identity matrix
  local pre_defined = string.rep("\0", 24)
  local next_track_ID = "\0\0\0\2"
  return version .. flags .. creation_time .. modification_time .. timescale .. duration ..
         rate .. volume .. reserved .. matrix .. pre_defined .. next_track_ID
end

local function create_tkhd_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\7"  -- track enabled, track in movie, track in preview
  local creation_time = "\0\0\0\0"
  local modification_time = "\0\0\0\0"
  local track_ID = "\0\0\0\1"
  local reserved = "\0\0\0\0"
  local duration = "\0\0\03\xe8"  -- 1 second duration
  local reserved2 = string.rep("\0", 8)
  local layer = "\0\0"
  local alternate_group = "\0\0"
  local volume = "\0\01\00\00"
  local reserved3 = "\0\0"
  local matrix = string.rep("\0", 36)  -- identity matrix
  local width = "\0\01\00\00"  -- 1.0
  local height = "\0\01\00\00"  -- 1.0
  return version .. flags .. creation_time .. modification_time .. track_ID .. reserved .. duration ..
         reserved2 .. layer .. alternate_group .. volume .. reserved3 .. matrix .. width .. height
end

local function create_mdhd_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local creation_time = "\0\0\0\0"
  local modification_time = "\0\0\0\0"
  local timescale = "\0\0\03\xe8"  -- 1000 units per second
  local duration = "\0\0\03\xe8"  -- 1 second duration
  local language = "\x55\xc4"  -- undetermined language
  local pre_defined = "\0\0"
  return version .. flags .. creation_time .. modification_time .. timescale .. duration .. language .. pre_defined
end

local function create_hdlr_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local pre_defined = "\0\0\0\0"
  local handler_type = "vide"  -- video track
  local reserved = string.rep("\0", 12)
  local name = "VideoHandler\0"
  return version .. flags .. pre_defined .. handler_type .. reserved .. name
end

local function create_vmhd_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\1"  -- default flags
  local graphics_mode = "\0\0"
  local opcolor = "\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  return version .. flags .. graphics_mode .. opcolor
end

local function create_dinf_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local entry_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local data_reference_box = "\0\0\0\x0c" .. "url " .. "\0\0\0\1"
  return version .. flags .. entry_count .. data_reference_box
end

local function create_stsd_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local entry_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local sample_entry = "\0\0\0\x86" .. "avc1" .. string.rep("\0", 24) .. "\0\0\0\1" .. "\0\0\0\0" .. "\0\0\0\0"
  return version .. flags .. entry_count .. sample_entry
end

local function create_stts_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local entry_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local sample_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local sample_delta = "\0\0\03\xe8"
  return version .. flags .. entry_count .. sample_count .. sample_delta
end

local function create_stsc_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local entry_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local first_chunk = "\0\0\0\1"
  local samples_per_chunk = "\0\0\0\1"
  local sample_description_index = "\0\0\0\1"
  return version .. flags .. entry_count .. first_chunk .. samples_per_chunk .. sample_description_index
end

local function create_stsz_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local sample_size = "\0\0\0\0"  -- non-uniform sample sizes
  local sample_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local sample_sizes = "\0\0\0\1"
  return version .. flags .. sample_size .. sample_count .. sample_sizes
end

local function create_stco_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local entry_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local chunk_offset = "\0\0\0\0"  -- placeholder offset
  return version .. flags .. entry_count .. chunk_offset
end

local function create_minf_box()
  local vmhd = create_vmhd_box()
  local dinf = create_dinf_box()
  local stbl = create_stsd_box() .. create_stts_box() .. create_stsc_box() .. create_stsz_box() .. create_stco_box()
  return vmhd .. dinf .. stbl
end

local function create_mdia_box()
  local mdhd = create_mdhd_box()
  local hdlr = create_hdlr_box()
  local minf = create_minf_box()
  return mdhd .. hdlr .. minf
end

local function create_trak_box()
  local tkhd = create_tkhd_box()
  local mdia = create_mdia_box()
  return tkhd .. mdia
end

local function create_moov_box()
  local mvhd = create_mvhd_box()
  local trak = create_trak_box()
  return mvhd .. trak
end

local function create_mdat_box()
  local data = string.rep("\0", 4)  -- placeholder for actual media data
  return data
end

local function create_frame_data(color)
  local width = 1280
  local height = 720
  local bytes_per_pixel = 3 -- RGB
  local frame_size = width * height * bytes_per_pixel

  local data = ""

  if color == "white" then
    for i = 1, frame_size do
      data = data .. "\xff"
    end
  elseif color == "black" then
    for i = 1, frame_size do
      data = data .. "\x00"
    end
  end

  return data
end

local function write_box(f, box_type, data)
  local size = 8 + #data
  f:write(string.pack(">I4", size))  -- Box size
  f:write(box_type)  -- Box type
  f:write(data)  -- Box data
end

local function create_mp4(filename, color)
  local f = assert(io.open(filename, "wb"))

  -- Write ftyp box
  write_box(f, "ftyp", create_ftyp_box())

  -- Write moov box
  write_box(f, "moov", create_moov_box())

  -- Write mdat box
  local frame_data = create_frame_data(color)
  write_box(f, "mdat", frame_data)

  f:close()
end

create_mp4("black_frame.mp4", "black")
create_mp4("white_frame.mp4", "white")

However, when I try to open the resulting MP4 files, they don't seem to work correctly. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm structuring the MP4 boxes or assembling the video frames.

Not to be dismissive, but this kind of question is surprisingly common. The answer is it isn't worth your time. Use a library. Requirements forbidding that are inane; anything you are running lua on already has libmp4 on it. Just link and use.

Ok! I'll try doing that, if it doesn't work i post another question about the linkage with libmp4, or add an answer in this question?

If your specific question changes then yes, create a new topic.

(1) rewrite half of ffmpeg in pure lua (2) done. -- voting to close. question is WAY too broad. -- do you really plan to write your own code to mux/demux mp4 containers, and then implement some video codec for the video stream that goes into the container? -- I'd recommend looking for bindings to ffmpeg... not the CLI, but the libraries of ffmpeg. do not touch anything that merely runs a subprocess. those "wrappers" are all junk. all of them. no exception. fundamentally not worth anyone's time.

@NiTerleski Writing an encoder of frame data is gonna be tricky but writing a muxer / demuxer is do-able. It's a skill worth having (eg: ability to trim MP4 by duration, extract or replace the audio track, replace specific video frames, etc)... You need to share a test output file that you made (for our checking if the bytes structure is correct) to get faster advice.

@NiTerleski from a quick look at your code I think I found some issues. I cannot test LUA code. Please share a file if possible (small 320x240 resolution).


"I'm looking for guidance on how to:"

Create video frames in Lua
Read frames from an existing MP4 file.


Decide which one and focus each of your StackOverflow questions on that topic. You can create frames with RGB data converted to YUV. It won't be compressed but it's okay for practice. Reading frames is just  Array operation (find elements, extract range of array elements, etc).
Get a hex editor to see the file structure of a working file versus your file.
Later when asking, you need to be specific about how or where you're stuck.

"I've written some Lua code to create an MP4 file with frames, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected..."

You must fix the following to be able to get a picture from a media player loading your file...

You don't have an STSS box (for listing keyframes).

The first frame must be of type: IDR keyframe. It's not clear if your frame data is raw YUV, or H.264, or H.265, or AV1 or VP9, etc. Find out what you have and identify the first given/found keyframe, those bytes is what you will mux as the first frame in your MP4 file.

About fixing function create_stsz_box():

Also try to add at least 2 frames (for a start & end frame). It can be same frame data copied twice.
local function create_stsz_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local sample_size = "\0\0\0\0"  -- non-uniform sample sizes
  local sample_count = "\x00\x00\x00\x02" -- total entries of sizes
  local sample_sizes_1 = "\0\0\0\1" -- use real size (bytes length) of frame 1
  local sample_sizes_2 = "\0\0\0\1" -- use real size (bytes length) of frame 2
  return version .. flags .. sample_size .. sample_count .. sample_sizes_1 .. sample_sizes_2
end

But now you must update STTS to have two time display entries. (called PTS and is related to the MDHD timescale entry).
local function create_stts_box()
  local version = "\0"  -- version 0
  local flags = "\0\0\0"
  local entry_count = "\0\0\0\1"
  local sample_count = "\0\0\0\2" -- use total frames as the sample count
  local sample_delta = "\0\0\03\xe8" -- one entry because we want Constant FPS mode for all frames
  return version .. flags .. entry_count .. sample_count .. sample_delta
end

Also fix the Duration numbers in TKHD and MVHD and finally in MDHD.
Good luck & share a file (link) for some checking, if still stuck.
